# K-Means for diagonal clusters

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I currently have 2 clusters which essentially lie along 2 lines on a 3D surface:

[image: Plot of the two clusters]

I've tried a simple kmeans algorithm which yielded the above separation. (Big red dots are the means)

I have tried clustering with soft k-means with different variances for each mean along the 3 dimensions. However, it also failed to model this, presumably as it cannot fit the shape of a diagonal Gaussian.

Is there another algorithm that can take into account that the data is diagonal? Alternatively is there a way to essentially "rotate" the data such that soft k-means could be made to work?

Comment: k-means is just a special case of learning a gaussian mixture model. General gaussian mixture models will capture the rotation as well.

Comment: If I had to guess it is more likely that the outliers are biasing your clustering towards the right. Try removing those outliers and attempt clustering again.

Answer (score 0):

K-means is not well prepared for correlations.

But these clusters look reasonably Gaussian to me, you should try **Gaussian Mixture Modeling** instead.